# declaring memory using malloc

Tags: c, malloc

```
gcc (GCC) 4.6.3
c89
apache runtime portable libraries
```

Hello,

Just a simple question I guess I am trying to create a uuid value.

I want me function that creates it to be stand alone (black box) so I can just pass a buffer and the function will do the rest.

Which means I have to declare memory on the heap in that function, as the calling function doesn't know much to declare. I know this a bad idea, as the callie will have to free the memory after it has finished with it.

Is there any way I can do this better?

When I run this the branch_id_buf is always null after the function returns. However, I have passed it to the function so should not be null when the function returns as it should point to some allocated memory.

Many thanks for any advice,

```
static void g_get_branch_id(char *branch_id_buf);

int main(void)
{
    char *branch_id_buf = NULL;

    g_get_branch_id(branch_id_buf);

    printf("branch id [ %s ]\n", branch_id_buf);

    free(branch_id_buf);

    return 0;
}

static void g_get_branch_id(char *branch_id_buf)
{
    apr_uuid_t uuid;

#define MAGIC_COOKIE_LENGTH 9

    const char *MAGIC_COOKIE = "z9hG4bk-";
    const int BRANCH_ID_LENGTH = APR_UUID_FORMATTED_LENGTH + MAGIC_COOKIE_LENGTH;

    branch_id_buf = malloc(BRANCH_ID_LENGTH);
    if(branch_id_buf == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    strncpy(branch_id_buf, MAGIC_COOKIE, BRANCH_ID_LENGTH);
    printf("branch id [ %s ]\n", branch_id_buf);
    apr_uuid_get(&uuid);

#define PREFIX_BRANCH_LENGTH 8
    apr_uuid_format(branch_id_buf + PREFIX_BRANCH_LENGTH, &uuid);

    printf("branch id [ %s ]\n", branch_id_buf);
}
```

Comment: malloc will return NULL if it failed to allocate memory. Are you sure you're not running out of resources when running this program?

Comment: what happens if you single step into g_get_branch_id() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is a very bad idea to allocate in one module and free in another. This is exactly how you create numerous memory leaks in your programs. Your code is particularly problematic, as you don't only leave freeing to the caller, but also the responsibility to initialize the pointer to NULL

That being said, it seems that you are only dealing with compile-time constants (?), so I don't understand why you even need malloc. Can't you do like this?

```
static const char MAGIC_COOKIE[] = "z9hG4bk-";

#define MAGIC_COOKIE_LENGTH (sizeof(MAGIC_COOKIE)/sizeof(char))

#define BRANCH_ID_LENGTH (APR_UUID_FORMATTED_LENGTH + MAGIC_COOKIE_LENGTH)


static void g_get_branch_id (char branch_id_buf [BRANCH_ID_LENGTH]);
```

The array length in the prototype indicates to the caller that they should pass a pointer to a buffer with that length.

Answer (score 3):

In the posted code, `branch_id_buf` is local to the function: any changes made will not be visible to the caller.

You need to pass a `char**`:

```
char *branch_id_buf = NULL;

g_get_branch_id(&branch_id_buf);

...

void g_get_branch_id(char **branch_id_buf) {

    /* Dereference 'branch_id_buf' within this function. */
    *branch_id_buf = malloc(BRANCH_ID_LENGTH);
```

EDIT:

As commented by [larsmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166749/larsmans), consider returning a `char*` rather than accepting an argument:

```
char *branch_id_buf = g_get_branch_id();

char* g_get_branch_id() {

    char* branch_id_buf = malloc(BRANCH_ID_LENGTH);
    ...
    return branch_id_buf;
}
```

Comment: Given that the function currently returns `void`, it's a much better idea to have it return a `char*` to the allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks, I did think about the pointer to pointer. But maybe just over looked it.

Answer (score 2):

Is is NOT a bad idea. Just be careful and remember to release that memory. There are few common techniques to make it even more safe; like reference counting or release pools.

Alternatively you can call your "black box" twice. First call to make such how much memory you will need and then second call with pointer to already allocated buffer.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but a initialize function to get the complete size I will need.

Comment: However, as this is just a function I would have to put the constants in there as well. I think I would be duplicated the constants. Something I am not keen to do. And I don't want to put them in a header file.

Comment: You CAN call sprintf(NULL, "%d", 10000); to get length (-1) of string long enough to store "10000". This is an example of my second thought.

Comment: +1 for 'NOT a bad idea'.  Being able to allocate memory and free it in the same module is a nice luxury that many developers don't have available to them.  In complex multithreaded apps, objects/structs/buffers come in on queues from other threads/modules developed by others and the cost/complexity of always signaling the stuff back to their originator vs. just dispose/delete/free on the spot is often just unreasonable.